# Error in SQL Query  Alter Table MySql 

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-error-1005

I get an error when executing the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE property_res_details 
ADD CONSTRAINT PropertyIdLink FOREIGN KEY ( Property_ID )  
REFERENCES properties( Property_ID )  ON DELETE CASCADE ;


#1005 - Can't create table './resfi/#sql-10e1_8df.frm' (errno: 150)
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.brainfault.com/2008/02/15/mysql-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-tablefrm-errno-150/) might give a clue as to what's going on...

Since you're adding a foreign key, it sounds relevant.
It suggests you try

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

to see the latest constraint error which may cause the error you're seeing.

Maybe if you try

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

before your command, it will disable the checks and allow you to continue?

Comment: You saved my day with this link. Thanks. I spend hours of investigating why the create fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't you just love MySQL's awesome error messages.

```
ADD CONSTRAINT PropertyIdLink FOREIGN KEY ( Property_ID )  
REFERENCES properties( Property_ID ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Make sure that the `Property_ID` columns have the **exact same datatype** in both tables. That's how I have fixed similar errors for myself in the past.